# После того как отправил нужные данные по сокету, его нужно закрывать?

Tags: java, сокет

То есть потом, для того что бы получить ещё данных просто заново открыть? Это не сильно нагружает сервер(открытие и закрытие сокетов)?

Comment: опять вы задаете вопросы по проекту не прикладывая код, вы не закрывате свои вопросы... Почитайте пару статей по работе с сокетами, там много ответов на ваши вопросы

Comment: Это обобщённый вопрос.

Comment: нагружает. но при этом http который основан именно на таком поведении самый используемый протокол. с другой стороны иногда полезно иметь открытый постоянно сокет по которому может поступить очередная порция данных (websocket все таки ввели, поняв что одним http сыт не будешь). с третьей стороны у процессов ОС есть серьезные ограничения на количество одновременно открытых сокетов

Comment: И да, ваш вопрос явно слишком общий, потому что единственным ответом на него может быть: надо использовать такое поведение сокетов, которое необходимо в конкретном случае их использования

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Общий вопрос - общий ответ. Открытое должно быть закрытое, а вот когда решать вам. Например если вы отрываете сокет для передачи информации типа статистики, то если статистику вам нужно обновлять каждые 5-10 сек, то закрытие сокета не целесообразно, а если в конце дня то после передачи данных сокет можно спокойно закрывать. Идеология следующая, сокет, http, Input/OutputStream(с файлом, то-есть системные), такие соединения лутше закрывать сразу, так как это системные ресурсы, возможно они кому-то понадобятся, но и открывать и закрывать постоянно безполезно. Пример можно привести с дверью, держать ее на распашку когда это вам не нада - будет холодно, вас просквозит, и при этом закрывать/открывать не нужно - можно сломать.